# Python: How to check if an input is an instance of a class within that class?

Tags: python, linked-list

I tried to write a code that protects the pointer of a linked list. The setter should point only to an instance which belongs to the same class.  Usually `isinstance()` or `type()` work after the class is defined.  But the setter is a method inside that class, hence the class is not fully defined yet.
I have no doubt that `type()` gives out error.  But I wonder why `isinstance(instance, class)` yields `False` if calling from another class.

```
#define the Node class
class Node:
    """Class Node contain only data and a next pointer variables."""
    def __init__(self, Data = None):
        self.data = Data
        self.__next = None

    def getNext(self):
        """The getter"""                
        return self.__next

    def setNext(self, NextNode):
        """The setter"""
        #if possible check if NewNode is an instance of Node before pointing to it.      
        #I have tried "isinstance(), type(), etc. but failed. 
        if isinstance(NextNode, Node):
            self.__next = NextNode
        else:
            print('The Next pointer should point to "Node" only.')
```

Then check if isinstance is working

```
ANode = Node((1,2,3))
BNode = Node((5,6))
ANode.setNext(BNode)
print(BNode)
print(ANode.getNext())
```

Both prints yield the same address

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x112162828>
<__main__.Node object at 0x112162828>
```

So everything looks fine. But When I call from the `LinkedList` class, printed below, the `isinstance` yields `False`, as seen from my warning.

```
class LinkedList:
    """This class is the Linked List of Node."""
    def __init__(self, FirstNode = None):
        """Initialize by creating an empty List.  __First hold the pointer that point to the first node."""
        if FirstNode is None:
            self.__first = Node(None)
            self.__last = self.__first
        elif type(FirstNode) is Node:
            self.__first = FirstNode
            self.__last = self.__first
        else:
            print('To create a linked-list enter nothing or a Node.')
            raise TypeError 

    def getFirst(self):
        return self.__first

    def append(self, NewLastNode):
        """Add LastNode to the end of the list."""
        if not isinstance(NewLastNode,Node):
            raise TypeError
        OldLast = self.__last
        OldLast.setNext(NewLastNode)
        self.__last = NewLastNode
        NewLastNode.setNext(None)

    def removeFirstNode(self):
        """Remove the first node (when the buffer is full)."""
        OldFirst = self.__first  
        NewFirst = OldFirst.getNext()
        if NewFirst == None:
            # just clear data                 
            OldFirst.data = None
        else:
            self.__first = NewFirst
            del OldFirst
```

Then I create an instance of the `LinkedList` class

```
LL = LinkedList(Node((1,2)))
NewNode = Node((2.0, 3.0, -10))
```

Surely `isinstance` works fine here

```
isinstance(NewNode,Node)
```

yields `True`, but

```
LL.append(NewNode)
```

which will call `Node.setNext()` and there the `isinstance()` yields `False` as the else in `Node.setNext()` prints out

```
The Next pointer should point to "Node" only.
```

Comment: Strange, I'd expect `isinstance()` to work just fine. It's true that the name `Node` isn't accessible in the direct class-level scope of the Node definition, but it _should_ be accessible inside methods belonging to Node, since you probably don't call them until after the class exists. Can you share the version of your code that uses `isinstance`?

Comment: `isinstance()` is what you want. If it's "failing," post the actual code you used and what problem you had with it.

Comment: Your code works fine, I tried using `isinstance` and got no error. I guess there's something else going wrong...

Comment: I have changed the setter code to:

    def setNext(self, NextNode):
        if isinstance(NextNode, Node):
            self.__next = NextNode
        else:
            print('The Next pointer should point to "Node" only.')

and then call: 
LL = LinkedList(Node((1,2)))
to create a list. Then instantiate a new node:
NewNode = Node((2.0, -10)). 
and check "isinstance(NewNode,Node)" which is 'True' outside.
But then I call LL.append(NewNode)
It gives out 'The Next pointer should point to "Node" only.'

Comment: @Wanchp can you please edit your question instead of adding the code in the comments? Otherwise it's really difficult to read it. Thanks!

Comment: This is secondary to your question, but assuming you get the class check working, you should use `self.__class__` rather than hard-coding `Node`.

Comment: And you also should never capitalize method parameter names like `NextNode` (use `next_node`).

Comment: What would you do if `NextNode` *wasn't* a `Node`, raise an exception? The only thing calling `isinstance` will do is help you track down the bug that passes a non-`Node` to `setNext` in the first place; it can't help you undo the damage once the value has already been passed.

Comment: This problem is really hard for us to reproduce because 30% of your code is in a screenshot and 30% of it is in a comment, and the code that _is_ in the question is improperly formatted (i.e. your `init` isn't in the code block). Please provide a properly formatted [mcve] all in one place.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your comment.  True it can't help me undoing the damage but at least my list is still a proper linked-list.  And it gives out warning!

Comment: @Kevin I am so sorry. What you said is absolutely true. But I am new here. I'll try to post the whole code (in a jupyter notebook format).

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer :-) It sounds like you put the complete code in LinkedList.ipynb. But unfortunately I can't access that file because I don't have a dropbox account. Can you please [edit] your question so that it contains all the code?

Comment: @Kevin I'll do it.  But you can access the file even you don't have a dropbox account.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks for you comment.  I just see your point (about self.__class__).   But the naming is just my style which I know a bit odd ;)

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code. You mentioned your example produces a _warning_  - you should also include that.

Comment: @wwii Thank you form your comment.  I have edited my question.  I am not sure if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code that's giving you the error is this:

```
NewLastNode.setNext(None)
```

because you're trying to set the next element to an object that it's not a `Node` instance, hence the error.
I think you could simply remove this statement, as your `self.__last` is now correctly pointing to your `NewLastNode`. So your code will become:

```
def append(self, NewLastNode):
    """Add LastNode to the end of the list."""
    if not isinstance(NewLastNode,Node):
        raise TypeError
    OldLast = self.__last
    OldLast.setNext(NewLastNode)
    self.__last = NewLastNode
```

Comment: Thank you so much @toti08! That's my careless.   And I removed the if clause in the append() because the isinstance() will be checked in the setNext().